# Laravel Error : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'categories' already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I cant figure out what the problem is, the 2 tables are not connecting for some reason, I read many articles and tried many things still not working.

I want to link post and category tables together, so when I can display the category chosen in the post made.

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('currency_id');
        });
    }
```

Category

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        });
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'categories' already exists (SQL: create table `categories` (`id`
>   bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at`
>   timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `name` varchar(255) not
>   null, `post_id` bigint unsigned not null) default character set
>   utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: What command do you use for the migration?

Comment: probable your database has an existing table `categories`

Comment: i know, even when i dropped the table and migrate it again it does not work

Comment: can you try removing `$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');` if this works.

Comment: I guess your Database migration files are wrong order. The first file for `posts` then `categories`.

Comment: removing it didnt work.. what to do mean its wrong can u explain more please

Comment: can you provide  migration names for both files.

Comment: 2020_03_31_082945_create_posts_table.php
...................
2020_03_31_083307_create_categories_table.php

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing you database entirely using the `migrate:refresh` artisan command.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

It may be that a database migration ran and failed before it could register in the `migrations` table of your database.

---

**Issues:** (so far)

1) As per above, a `migrate:refresh` sorts out the original error

2) `$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();` will not work as `posts.id` is an `integer` and not a `bigInteger`.

**Solution:**

Change your `post_id` definition to

```
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Dropped all tables and tried again .. still 
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`categories` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`))

Comment: Ok, that is a different error at least. It is now complaining about a foreign key. This could be due to the order in which your migrations are being executed. Make sure you create your `posts` table before your `categories` table, otherwise your foreign key will fail

Comment: post migration is before the category migration .

Comment: See my updated answer, i've run into this a few times before when they changed the default for the id columns from `integer` to `bigInteger` but hadn't updated all of the documentation to reflect it (i.e. the examples they gave had the wrong definitions)

Answer (score 0):

It says the *categories* table already exists. So what you have to do is, If you are in dev env, you can delete the table and try it or you can do like the below command.

Run artisan like this, it will drop all tables and migrate fresher.

`php artisan migrate:fresh`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, you have to change `$table->increments('id')` in **posts** table to `$table->id()`, because the foreign key must refer to a primary key as the message says.

### Here are some tips for you

- You have to use `bigIncrements` in the **posts** table instead `integer` because the length of `integer` is **4-byte** but the `bigIncrements` is **8-byte** and this may cause a problem in the future
- You may love to use this line

```
$table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained();
```

instead

```
$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
```

for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Though, this is a past issue, but I found a very good and simple solution to this issue;

1. **Check your category and post migration file**
   Check your migration files and check the `public function up` and `public function down` if the tables_names are correct and then check on your http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php and then go to your database
2. **Checking migrations table**
   Inside your database, check for the `migrations` table, It looks like this
   [Picture of some rows inside a migrations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpDQT.png), you will find out that those two tables(post and category) are not inside
3. **Copy Names of Migrations Files**
   Go into your `laravel-app/database/migrations` folder or IDE to that folder named migrations, then copy the name of both migrations files
4. **Create new Migration rows and paste the copied names**
   Back to your localhost database migrations table, create new rows for the two copied names and paste the names accordingly numerically
   AND
   THEN RUN THE MIGRATION AGAIN. IT IS DONE

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was artisan/laravel cached somewhere migration
so i run `php artisan optimize:clear`
and it worked without an error any more

Answer (score 0):

You have a second categories table; delete the last categories table and your migration command will work.